# return error from update

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am calling updateUser from the client:

```
Meteor.call('updateUser', userObject, function (error, result) {
  console.log(error, result);

  if (error) {
    Meteor._debug("updateUser", "Failed to update user: " + error);
  }
});
```

returns on client: "undefined 0"

runs on server and client:

```
Meteor.methods({
  updateUser: function (userObject) {
    User.update({ _id: userObject._id }, { $set: userObject }, function (error, result) {
      console.log(error, result);

      if (error) {
        if (this.isSimulation) {
          console.log(error);
        } else {
          throw new Meteor.Error("updateUser", "failed to update user");
        }
      }
    });
  }
});
```

returns on server: a "notUnique" error

returns on client: "undefined undefined"

How do I return this error from the server to the client which calls the Meteor method `updateUser`? I need the error to know which type of error that occurred.

Comment: the only thing that seem to actually return any error thats not just "500 server error", which doesnt tell the client what went wrong, is to do the update within a try/catch to get the mongo error and then manipulate the returned string to be able to get the type of error.

Comment: Why not use the sync mechanism of `update` (assuming this is a `Mongo.Collection`)? Assign the result to a variable and don't provide a callback. This will only work as intended on the server, but in your case it should do the trick. In addition, you should not try to `$set` an object with the `_id`, as it already exists in the collection (in the document you are overwriting).

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to send the error details as string to the client. Details is the third optional parameter to [Meteor.Error](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_error)

Got the question. It is optimistic update in action. The client result is coming from results of minimongo update. The server throws an exception. It does not reach the client because the client has optimistically updated, and later refreshed itself with server data. To see exception, make it server method only.

Comment: `throw new Meteor.Error("a", "b", e);` returns `undefined undefined` on the client.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you have to use futures or promises because it is async

```
function attemptUpdate(userObject) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    User.update({ _id: userObject._id }, { $set: userObject }, function (error, result) {
      console.log(error, result);

      if (error) {
        if (this.isSimulation) {
          console.log(error);
          resolve(result);
        } else {
          reject(Meteor.Error("updateUser", "failed to update user"));
        }
      }
    });
  });
}

Meteor.methods({
  async updateUser(userObject) {
    await attemptUpdate.call(this, userObject);
  }
});
```